# How to add total number of items using list/conditional statments

Tags: python, processing

trying to write a code where when a certain key is pressed, the word pops up on the canvas (in this case they are all drinks). When the user keeps pressing the certain keys to add a drink, the total cost adds up.

However, the only thing in my code the works is the word "water" and the total cost keeps overlaying.

How do I fix my code so that each menu item appears on the canvas and how to fix the total cost?

(I attempted to move the background colour around however it still did not work. Also this coding is from processing, and it is not java script)

```
def setup():
    size (500, 500)
    background (255)

menu = ["Mocha","Coffee","Juice","water"]
prices = [5,2,3,1]
order = []
total = ''
cost = 0

Mocha = 5
Coffee = 2
Juice = 3
Water = 1
undo = -1
space = 0
i = 0
str1= 1

def draw():
    global total
    space = 100
    fill (0)
    line(250,0,250,500)
    textSize (30)
    text("Menu", 60, 50)

    textSize (15)
    for i in range(len(menu)):
        str1 = menu[i] + " : $" + str(prices[i])
        text(str1, 70, space)
        space = space+20

    textSize (30)
    text( "Your Order:", 260,50)
    textSize (15)
    #total = text("Cost : $0", 300,450)
    total= text(str1, 350, 450)

def keyPressed():
    global space
    global cost, total, menu, str1, i
    if key == 'm' :
        i=0
    elif key == 'c' :
        i=1
    elif key == 'j' :
        i=2
    elif key == 'w' :
        i=3
    elif undo == 'u' :
        i=-1
    space = space+20

    if i == -1 :
        if len(order) > 0:
            menu = order.pop(0)
            menu.pop(item)
    for i in range(len(menu)):
        if menu[i] == str1 :
            cost = cost - prices[i]
            menu.pop(total)
            str1 = "Cost : $" + str(cost)
            total= text(str1, 350, 450)

    else :
        order.append(text( menu[i], 300, space+90))
        cost = cost+prices[i]
        str1 = "Cost : $" + str(cost)
        total = text( str1, 360, 450)
```

Comment: The key which was pressed, when the [`keyPressed`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) function is called, is contained in the system variable [`key`](https://processing.org/reference/key.html). You have to compare the variable `key` to the character `'m'`, `'c'`, `'j'`, `'w'` and `'u'`.

Comment: okay so I just changed it to be  if key =="j" but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

The total cost keeps overlaying itself because the stage is not being cleared between draw() loops. Add `background(255)` at the top of the draw loop so that the stage is refreshed. Doing this however will introduce the need to loop through the order and draw its contents in the "Your Order:" section each loop.

You're getting name clashes with the variable `i`, which is making your code perform oddly. Remove the `i = 0` declaration near the top of your program. This fixes the "water"-only issue.

This needs to be changed: `order.append(text( menu[i], 300, space+90))`. You can't add Processing draw (`text()`) methods to an array like this.

Putting this all together (and a few more things) gives us this:

```
def setup():
size (500, 500)
background (255)

menu = ["Mocha","Coffee","Juice","Water"]
prices = [5,2,3,1]
order = []
cost = 0

def draw():
    background(255)

    fill(0)
    line(250,0,250,500)
    textSize (30)
    text("Menu", 60, 50)

    space = 100
    textSize (15)
    for i in range(len(menu)):
        str1 = menu[i] + " : $" + str(prices[i])
        text(str1, 70, space)
        space = space+20

    textSize (30)
    text( "Your Order:", 260,50)

    textSize (15)
    text("Cost : $" + str(cost), 350, 450)

    for ypos, item in enumerate(order):
        text(menu[item] + ".... $" + str(prices[item]), 270, ypos*20 + 80) 

def keyPressed():
    global cost, menu
    if key == 'm' :
        i=0
    elif key == 'c' :
        i=1
    elif key == 'j' :
        i=2
    elif key == 'w' :
        i=3
    elif key == 'u' :
        i=-1
    else: # do nothing if the key is undefined
        return

    if i == -1 :
        if len(order) > 0:
            cost -= prices[order[-1]] # subtract cost
            order.pop() # pop the order, not the menu!
    else :
        cost += prices[i]
        order.append(i)
```